# Конвертор шрифтов

Tags: шрифты, html, css

Подскажите пож-та конвертор, который будет русские шрифты из формата ttf будет конвертировать в eot, woff, svg? А то нужно для подгрузки своего шрифта таким образом:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "JournalRegular";
    src: url("journal-webfont.eot");
    src: url("journal-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("journal-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("journal-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("journal-webfont.svg#JournalRegular") format("svg");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[font-face Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

Comment: Спасибо, отличный конвертер!

Answer (score 0):

Вот этот тоже хороший сервис. Просто font-face Generator имеет чёрный список, и я столкнулся с тем, что он мне не конвертировал некоторые шрифты, и писал что шривт в ЧС.
[OnlineFontConverter](http://onlinefontconverter.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/204432/css-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82-ttf-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-eot-woff-%D0%B8-svg), там больше альтернативных вариантов.