# Где можно форматировать шрифт ttf в форматы eot, woff и svg?

Tags: css3, веб-программирование, шрифты, css

Есть шрифт с кириллицей в формате `ttf`. Где можно форматировать его в eot, woff и svg?
На [Webfont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) при загрузке шрифта на сайт получаю ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот эти конверторы:

[CodeAndMore @font-face made simple tool](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/indexnew.php)

[onlinefontconverter.com](http://onlinefontconverter.com/)

[freefontconverter.com](http://www.freefontconverter.com/)

Answer (score 2):

[Font2Web](http://www.font2web.com/)

P.S. А что за ошибку на Squirrel выбивает? Может проблема с самим шрифтом?

Answer (score 0):

У вас свой уникальный шрифт? Если нет, вам могут подойти [webfont.ru](http://webfont.ru) или [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts)